# $\int_0^x g(x-a)f(a)da=\int_0^x f(a)da$ - Please help to explain the error

Tags: integration, convolution, fake-proofs

Let $I$ be an integral function s.t.

$$I(f(x))= \int_0^x f(a)\,da.$$

Let $g$ be a function s.t. $g(0)=1$ and $g_x(a):=g(x-a)$.

I have

\begin{align}
\int_0^x g_x(a)f(a)\,da& =I(g_x(x)f(x)) \\[8pt]
& =I(f(x)) \\[8pt]
& =\int_0^x f(a)\,da
\end{align}

Ie:

If $g(0)=1$, then $\int_0^x g(x-a)f(a)\,da=\int_0^x f(a)\,da$.

I notice this is wrong, but 'd like so much any explanation. I thought I cannot get the first equality because $g_x$ also depends on $x$. If this is the explanation, I'd like to know if there some way of write $g(x)\ast f(x)=\int_0^x g_x(a)f(a)\,da$ as an integral function.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think this this is an example where one gets confused by using bad notation. The notation should be $I(f)(x)=\int_0^x f(a)\,da$. Therefore $I(g_x\cdot f)(y)=\int_0^y g(x-a)f(a)\,da$, and I presume your $I(g_x(x)f(x))$ is supposed to stand for the function $x\mapsto I(g_x\cdot f)(x)$.

Comment: Bright comment, you're right... Many thanks. So... Do not I can get anything new of $I(g_x\cdot f)(x)$ knowing that $g_x(x)=1$...?

Comment: You are integrating, therefore the specific value of $g$ at one point is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you so much, maybe you could post the two comments as an answer!

Comment: How did you get $\displaystyle \int_0^x g_x(a)f(a)\,da =I(g_x(x)f(x)) \text{ ?} $ (And BTW, I corrected your formatting. Take a look at my edit to this question.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy, first of all many thanks for your edit. Second, this equality was from my definition $I(f(x))= \int_0^x f(a)\,da$ that was bad definition ($f(x) \mapsto \int_0^x f(a)\,da$)... I should mean $I(f)(x)= \int_0^x f(a)\,da$ ($x \mapsto \int_0^x f(a)\,da$)... Could you understand my error...? Many thanks.

Comment: @Na'omi : No, I still don't understand how you did that?

Comment: $I(f(x))= \int_0^x f(a)\,da\Longrightarrow I(g_x(x)f(x))=I((g_xf)(x))= \int_0^x(g_x f)(a)\,da=\int_0^x g_x(a) f(a)\,da$. I am not sure I understand the doubt, Mr. Hardy, but this can explain? Many thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume this is an instance of confusion coming from a bad notation. The notation should be $I(f)(x)=\int_0^x f(a)\,da$, and therefore $I(g_yf)(x)=\int_0^x g(y-a)f(a)\,da$. I presume your $I(g_x(x)f(x))$ is supposed to stand for the function $x\mapsto I(g_xf)(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am thinking. Suppose that $D$ is the derivative operator. So, $DI(f)(x)=f(x)$, right? So, $DI(g_xf)(x)=(g_xf)(x)=f(x)$?

Comment: If $g$ were smooth, I'd say that the correct guess would be $f(x)+\int_0^x g'(x-a)f(a)\,da$.

Comment: You say Leibniz rule? I think you're correct. Many thanks.